# Sequlize get associate table data

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

```
I am using Sequlize PostgreSQL. I have some table below

Campaigna( id, title )

BPCampaigna( id,  user_id(forignkey), campaign_Id(forigen_key) )

Usera( id, name, conatct )
```

I am trying to get all campaign with all bp and and details of every bp like

```
{
    id: 1,
    title: 'campaign title',
    bp:{
       id: 1,
       name: 'Bp'
       conatct: '454545
    }

}
```

I have tried to find campaigns inlude BPCampaign then its working fine but when trying to find including Bpcampaign, users then error occuring.

```
 Campaign.findAll({
        where: {
            deleted: 0
        },
        include: [
        {
            model: relatedModel,
            include: [User]
        }
    ]
    })
```

err: `users is not associated to bp_campaigns!`

Comment: show the models' associations.

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/sXC3rqdYWZ/ @Anatoly

Comment: I have changed my query and error also changed, please have a look on question again.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't define associations for BpCampaign

```
BpCampaign.belongsTo(user, { foreignKey: 'aquisition_member_id' });
```

Comment: error: bp_campaigns.belongsTo called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model. 
this error showing now. is there need a migration ?

Comment: just create a new js-file associations.js and import all models into it. Then move all associations into it including BpCampaign.belongsTo. Instead of user you should point to created user model object.

Comment: where i need to add  the association.js file ?

Comment: The same plece whre your create your models and where you import your models like this const bp_campaign = require('./BpCampaign')

Comment: const User = require('../models/User')
const Campaign = require('../models/Campaign')
const BPCampaign = require('../models/BpCampaign')

Campaign.hasMany(BPCampaign, { foreignKey: 'campaign_id' }, {onDelete: 'CASCADE'});

User.hasMany(BPCampaign, { foreignKey: 'aquisition_member_id' }, {onDelete: 'CASCADE'});

BpCampaign.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: 'aquisition_member_id' });

Comment: const Association = require('../models/associations');

Comment: error:campaigns.hasMany called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model

Comment: Did you remove the line Campaign.hasMany(bp_campaign, { foreignKey: 'campaign_id' }, {onDelete: 'CASCADE'}) from Campaign file?

Comment: Yes I have deleted that.

Comment: I have solved the issue.. But don,t understanding what is the different with your solution..

Comment: In user table I have required bp_campaign and added ......      bp_campaign.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: 'aquisition_member_id' });
User.hasMany(bp_campaign, { foreignKey: 'aquisition_member_id' });                            Now it is working ..\